# Bootstrap/CSS div not floating left/right

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

I am trying to get my divs to float left for the first then float right for the second etc. I've been trying it using float and bootstrap 5 float also. Neither of them works; I've googled about it and can't seem to find anything about it.

The plan is to have a background image but for now, I am simply using colored divs these being red and blue.

Any help would be great!

```css
   /*Main*/
   @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato&display=swap');

   html, body
   {
       width: 100%;
       height: 100%;
       margin: 0px;
       padding: 0px;
       overflow-x: hidden; 
       background-color: #0f2471;
       font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
      }

 /*NavBar ;*/

   #logo-space{
     width: auto;
     height: auto;
   }

   #logo-space img{
     width: 5010;
     height: auto;
     position: relative;
     left: 2.5rem;
   }

   #fms-btn{
      width: 120px;
      position: relative;
      top: 1rem;
      right: 2rem;
      height: 60px;
      font-size: 1rem;
      justify-content: center;

      text-decoration: none !important; 
      background-color: #030b29;
      color: white;
    }

   .nav-bar{
       background-color: #16377e;
       position: relative;
   }
 
   #navbar-space .nav-link{
     position: relative;
     left: 4rem;
   }


   #home-img{
    /* to remove space between images, because car image has this wave and page background would be visable */
  margin-bottom: -86px;
}

  #home-img img{
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
  }

  #about-us{
  background-color: white;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: 2;
  /* probably padding needed */
  color: black;
  height: 50vh;
  }

  #about-title{
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 45px;
  }

  #about-text{
    font-size: large;
  }

  #learn-more-btn{
  width: 15rem;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none !important; 
  background-color: #030b29;
  color: white;
  }

  #ee{
    width: auto;
    padding-top: 10px;
    height: 70%;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  .outer-div{
    background-color: white;
    width: 120%;
    height: 100%;
  }

  #police-div{
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 50px;
    padding-right: -1rem;
    float: left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    text-overflow: unset;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: large;
  }

  #ambulance-div{
    background-color: blue;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 50px;
    padding-right: -1rem;
    float: left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    text-overflow: unset;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: large;
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 400px){

    body{
      margin: 0;
      font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
      width: 100%;
    }

    #logo-space{
      width: auto;
      height: auto;

    }
 
    #logo-space img{
      width: auto;
      height: auto;
      position: relative;
      left: -1.5rem;
    }
 
    #fms-btn{
       width: 120px;
       position: relative;
       top: -1rem;
        right: 2px;
       height: 60px;
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
       font-size: 1rem;
       justify-content: center;
 
       text-decoration: none !important; 
       background-color: #030b29;
       color: white;
     }

     .nav-bar{
      margin-top: -10px;
     }

     #about-us{
      background-image: url('./img/l3.png');
      background-position: center;
      background-size: cover;
      z-index: 2;
      /* probably padding needed */
      padding: 25vh 0;
      color: black;
      height: 50%;
    }

    #about-text{
      font-size: small;
      width: 15rem;
      position: relative;
      bottom: 25vh;
      font-size: small;
    }

    #about-title{
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 20px;
      position: relative;
      bottom: 25vh;
    }

    #learn-more-btn{
      width: 5rem;
      font-size: 18px;
      text-decoration: none !important; 
      background-color: #16377e;
      color: white;
      position: relative;
      right: 1rem;
      
      text-align: center;
    }

    #redirect-symbol{
      position: relative;
      left: 3px;
    }

    #ee{
      height: 120%;
      position: relative;
      bottom: 11rem;
    }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <!--When Site is finished, check all compats-->
  <head>
    <title>Testing</title>
    <!--CSS-->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!--Font Awesome-->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/b5212ab333.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!--Index Stylesheet-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/divstyle.css">
    <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kQtW33rZJAHjgefvhyyzcGF3C5TFyBQBA13V1RKPf4uH+bwyzQxZ6CmMZHmNBEfJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rubik" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 

    <style type="text/css"></style>
  </head>

  <body>
    
  <body style="margin: 0;">

        <!--Logo Space-->
        <div id="logo-space">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
            <img id="logo" src="img/logo.png" class="image-fluid" alt="">
            </div>

            <button id="fms-btn" type="button" class="btn  mx-4 m-3">
                <span class="text-center" style="text-decoration: none;">Head to FMS</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        </div>

    <!--Nav Bar-->
    <div id="home">
        <nav id="navbar-space" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg nav-bar">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active text-white" aria-current="page" href="./index.html">HOME</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#about">ABOUT US</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link text-white " href="./divisons.html">DIVISIONS</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link text-white " href="#appeals">APPEALS</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        </nav>
    </div>

    <!--  Top image GTA, there is no text so it can be <img> tag -->
    <div id="home-img" style="position: relative; z-index: 2;">
        <img src="/img/div/bg1.png" alt="">
    </div>
    
      <!--  About us section, with car in background -->
      <div id="about-us" style="position: relative; z-index: 3;">
          <!--  Your regular columns and content -->
          <div class="container-md">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
              <div id="about-title" class="col-4 about-text-header"> 
                <span style="text-decoration: none;">What do we offer?</span> 
                <div class="row" class="">
                  <button id="learn-more-btn" type="button" class="btn justify-content-center mx-4 m-3">
                         <img id="redirect-symbol" src="img/redirect.png" class="text-center" alt="" width="30" height="30" style="padding-right: 5px;">
                         <span class="text-center" style="text-decoration: none;">Learn More</span>
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div id="about-text" class="col-4 text-wrap">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil tempore cumque cupiditate alias nostrum ad beatae neque mollitia. Molestiae blanditiis voluptatum necessitatibus dolore omnis iure tenetur repellendus quis consequatur magni. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum quo, ducimus tempore sit mollitia reprehenderit.
                  </p>
              </div>
              <div class="row justify-content-center">
                    <img id="ee" src="./img/div/ee.png" alt="">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  
      <div id="about-divisions">
        <div class="" style="color: white;">
          <div class="row">

            <div class="container">
              <div class="col-12">
                <div id="police-div" class="text-center">
                  <div class="col-3">
                    <h2 class="" style="text-decoration: underline;">Lorem, ipsum.</h2>
                    <p class="px-4 py-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Et vitae deleniti aliquid architecto, libero, consequatur natus inventore dolorem labore accusamus autem laborum reprehenderit harum. Vitae doloribus possimus debitis ipsam nisi repellendus, at corporis necessitatibus mollitia modi asperiores qui natus quas. Similique voluptatem perspiciatis recusandae architecto dolore. Itaque expedita est sequi.</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="container" style="float: left;">
              <div class="col-12">
                <div id="ambulance-div" class="text-center">
                  <div class="col-3">
                    <h2 class="" style="text-decoration: underline;">Lorem, ipsum.</h2>
                    <p class="px-4 py-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Et vitae deleniti aliquid architecto, libero, consequatur natus inventore dolorem labore accusamus autem laborum reprehenderit harum. Vitae doloribus possimus debitis ipsam nisi repellendus, at corporis necessitatibus mollitia modi asperiores qui natus quas. Similique voluptatem perspiciatis recusandae architecto dolore. Itaque expedita est sequi.</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>


          </div>

        </div>        
      </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: the `<body>` tag is open twice at the beginning and the `margin: 0` is already defined in the css

Comment: instead of `float` why wouldnt you use `flexbox`?

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correct your question do it similar like this

```css
#ambulance-div{background: red; color: #FFF;}
#police-div{background: blue; color: #FFF;}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid p-0">
  <div class="row g-0">
     <div class="col-6">
       <div id="police-div" class="text-center">
         <h2 class="" style="text-decoration: underline;">Lorem, ipsum.</h2>
         <p class="px-4 py-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Et vitae deleniti aliquid architecto, libero, consequatur natus inventore dolorem labore accusamus autem laborum reprehenderit harum. Vitae doloribus possimus debitis ipsam nisi repellendus, at corporis necessitatibus mollitia modi asperiores qui natus quas. Similique voluptatem perspiciatis recusandae architecto dolore. Itaque expedita est sequi.</p>
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row g-0">
     <div class="col-6 offset-6">
       <div id="ambulance-div" class="text-center">
         <h2 class="" style="text-decoration: underline;">Lorem, ipsum.</h2>
         <p class="px-4 py-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Et vitae deleniti aliquid architecto, libero, consequatur natus inventore dolorem labore accusamus autem laborum reprehenderit harum. Vitae doloribus possimus debitis ipsam nisi repellendus, at corporis necessitatibus mollitia modi asperiores qui natus quas. Similique voluptatem perspiciatis recusandae architecto dolore. Itaque expedita est sequi.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: To answer this no, I want them on one row each so the red will be below the blue and floated to the right.

Comment: @Welshy1235 please see updated answer, should work

Comment: It works fine however, is there anyway to align the text into the blue section?
https://gyazo.com/e777747be28e61721c410374c01e0cba

Answer (score 0):

instead of using float, you can use flex or div row col classes that can help you more then float